# Best way to incorporate a query inside of the PIVOT IN list?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

so I'm trying to come up with a payroll worksheet and here's what I got:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (
    SELECT
        CAST(ad.EmplName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS [EmplName],
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), CAST(ad.TicketDate AS DATE), 1) AS [TicketDate],
        ROUND(ad.TotActTime, 2) AS [TotalHrs]
    FROM AttendDet ad
    WHERE ad.EmplCode IS NOT NULL
        AND ad.AttendCode <> '9999'
        AND CONVERT(DATE, ad.TicketDate) BETWEEN '20181022' AND '20181027'
    ) AS BaseData
PIVOT
    (
    SUM(BaseData.TotalHrs)
    FOR BaseData.TicketDate
        IN
        (
        [10/22/18],[10/23/18],[10/24/18],[10/25/18],[10/26/18],[10/27/18], [10/28/18]
        )
    ) AS PivotTable
```

Now that query works as expected, results are as follows:

[image]

The problem is having to type in the dates inside of IN within PIVOT.  What would be the best way to do this automatically with a list from a query?

If I have a list of dates and let's say I always wanted to look at the previous week, then the code below can generate that:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), CAST(DATEADD(dd,((DATEDIFF(dd,'17530101',GETDATE())/7)*7)-7,'17530101') AS DATE), 1)
UNION
SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), CAST(DATEADD(dd,((DATEDIFF(dd,'17530101',GETDATE())/7)*7)-6,'17530101') AS DATE), 1)
UNION
SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), CAST(DATEADD(dd,((DATEDIFF(dd,'17530101',GETDATE())/7)*7)-5,'17530101') AS DATE), 1)
UNION
SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), CAST(DATEADD(dd,((DATEDIFF(dd,'17530101',GETDATE())/7)*7)-4,'17530101') AS DATE), 1)
UNION
SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), CAST(DATEADD(dd,((DATEDIFF(dd,'17530101',GETDATE())/7)*7)-3,'17530101') AS DATE), 1)
UNION
SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), CAST(DATEADD(dd,((DATEDIFF(dd,'17530101',GETDATE())/7)*7)-2,'17530101') AS DATE), 1)
UNION
SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), CAST(DATEADD(dd,((DATEDIFF(dd,'17530101',GETDATE())/7)*7)-1,'17530101') AS DATE), 1)
```

Problem is, I have no idea how to incorporate that into my IN.  I've looked up some questions that refer to doing it via dynamic SQL, but honestly, I've no idea what that even is and I'm having a hard time trying to apply those examples to my case.  Is there another way of doing this?  Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: Because the column names are dynamic you need to use dynamic sql.

Answer (score 2):

I have been working something related these days. You may try this one; review and update it looking into your data. For further explanation, may you review the link attached on the comment.

```
Declare @start_date datetime 
Declare @end_date datetime 
Declare @attendance_code int

DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @columns = N'';
SELECT @columns += N', p.' + QUOTENAME(BASEData.TicketDate) 
FROM (SELECT
        CAST(ad.EmplName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS [EmplName],
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), CAST(ad.TicketDate AS DATE), 1) AS [TicketDate],
        ROUND(ad.TotActTime, 2) AS [TotalHrs]
    FROM AttendDet ad 
    GROUP BY p.BASEData.TicketDate) AS x; 
SET @sql = N'

SELECT ' + STUFF(@columns,1,2,'') + ' 
    (
    SELECT
        CAST(ad.EmplName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS [EmplName],
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), CAST(ad.TicketDate AS DATE), 1) AS [TicketDate],
        ROUND(ad.TotActTime, 2) AS [TotalHrs]
    FROM AttendDet ad
    WHERE ad.EmplCode IS NOT NULL
        AND ad.AttendCode <> '''@attendance_code'''
        AND CONVERT(DATE, ad.TicketDate) BETWEEN + '''CONVERT(VARCHAR, @start_date)''' AND + '''CONVERT(VARCHAR,@end_date)'''  
    ) AS BaseData
PIVOT
    (
    SUM(BaseData.TotalHrs)
    FOR BaseData.TicketDate
        IN
        (' STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', p.[', ',['), 1, 1, '') 
    ) AS PivotTable;'; 
PRINT @sql; 
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: @user1452574 Please check this link https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2783/script-to-create-dynamic-pivot-queries-in-sql-server/

Comment: Wow, thanks for your answer!! I can't quite figure out all the syntax errors, but I'll go through the link provided and hopefully I can figure it out